# Lost in alien world - Comic book identification

Tags: story-identification, comics

I am looking for a comic book / series (likely 60's or early 70's) in which a mixed crew of men and women (I remember them to be youngish) get lost in an alien but very Earthlike world only with giant-sized humanlike aliens.

I think after their ship crash-lands on that planet. They are looking for a power source to fix their spaceship. In the episode I read, they try to steal a battery from a supermarket or mall-like store.

I need help to identify and hopefully locate a copy which I can buy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds exactly like *Land of the Giants*, and per Wikipedia there was a tie-in comic made in 1968.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_of_the_Giants

Hermes Press sells a graphic novel featuring all five issues, digitally cleaned up:

http://www.hermespress.com/Books/Allen/landofthegiants.html